# Zookeeper general log or "monitor" command

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I want see all commands issued to my Zookeeper cluster, something like general log in MySQL or "monitor" command in Redis. How can this be done?

The intent is to see how Storm uses Zookeeper (for state management & ack-ing) and a good way to would be to run a sample topology and see all the commands issued to Zookeeper by Storm.

I tried enabling debug log for Zookeeper, but that is insufficient has a lot of noise. For example, issue a create /node prints

2018-02-27 18:05:34 ZooKeeperMain [DEBUG] Processing create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've found till now.

- Parse the Zookeeper transaction logs. 
  The best repo I've found to do this is https://github.com/alenca/zklogtool. It's feature packed. The only downside is that it won't record the read queries.
- Enable debug logging and grep for `Processing request::`. This is a hit and miss. Sometimes the request paths are not captured and will need you enable debug logging which can be expensive on a production server.